# Collection in ViewModel gone after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, collections, binding

I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class ActivityReportViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<int, List<string>> Periods { get; set; }

    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    public List<Templates> Templates { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimePeriod { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }
    public bool XLSX { get; set; }
    public bool PDF { get; set; }
}
```

I fill this ViewModel in my controller and then send it to my Create view, which works fine and the values of the Projects property are all there. However, when I postback the data to the server, the values are gone. I tried supplying HiddenFields to all properties of each Project to no avail. Here's my relevant view markup:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Projects, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "ms-Label" })
    <ul class="ms-List" style="list-style:none;">
        @for (int x = 0; x < Model.Projects.Count; x++)
        {
            <li class="ms-ListItem">
                <span class="ms-ListItem-primaryText">@Model.Projects[x].ProjectDescription</span> 
                <span class="ms-ListItem-secondaryText">@Model.Projects[x].Customer</span> 
                <span class="ms-ListItem-tertiaryText">@Model.Projects[x].ProjectNumber</span> 
                @*<div class="ms-ListItem-selectionTarget js-toggleSelection"></div>*@
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Projects[x].IsSelected)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Projects[x].ProjectDescription)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Projects[x].Customer)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Projects[x].ProjectNumber)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Projects[x].XLSX)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Projects[x].PDF)
                <div class="ms-Dropdown">
                    <i class="ms-Dropdown-caretDown ms-Icon ms-Icon--caretDown"></i>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Projects[x].TemplateId, new SelectList(Model.Templates, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "ms-Dropdown-select" })
                </div>
                <div class="ms-ChoiceField">
                    <input id="excel+@Model.Projects[x].ProjectNumber" class="ms-ChoiceField-input" value="@Model.Projects[x].XLSX" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="excel+@Model.Projects[x].ProjectNumber" class="ms-ChoiceField-field"><span class="ms-Label is-required">Excel</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="ms-ChoiceField">
                    <input id="pdf+@Model.Projects[x].ProjectNumber" class="ms-ChoiceField-input" value="@Model.Projects[x].PDF" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="pdf+@Model.Projects[x].ProjectNumber" class="ms-ChoiceField-field"><span class="ms-Label is-required">PDF</span></label>
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    <div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Projects, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>            
</div>
```

EDIT:

Here's my POST action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ActivityReportViewModel report)
{
    using (AppContainer _db = new AppContainer())
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return PartialView(report);
    }

}
```

Comment: Show the POST Create Action.

Comment: If you delete the code in both your `<div class="ms-ChoiceField">` elements (which makes not sense and is not binding to anything - not really sure what you think that code would ever do) then the `Projects` property of your model will be correctly populated. If its not, then you have other code you have not shown us that is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

The `DefaultViewModel` Binder uses the HTML attribute `name` to determine which property to bind back to on the server. I cannot see `name` attribute specified on your input element. Please specify `name` attribute on the elements you wish to post back to the server with the property of the view model.

Specifiy `name` attribute as below. Notice I have added `name` attribute with value as the property of your view model

```
<input id="excel+@Model.Projects[x].ProjectNumber" class="ms-ChoiceField-input" name="@Model.Projects[x].ProjectNumber" value="@Model.Projects[x].XLSX" type="checkbox">
```